# How to make bootstrap-multiselect invisible my default?

Tags: jquery, show-hide, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am using the [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin to make dealing with drop down menu easier. However, I am having an issue when trying to make the menu hidden by default.

Basically, I have a check box, when this check box is check then I display the drop down men. And when it is unchecked the menu should become hidden. The check box is unchecked by default so I want the menu to be hidden by default as well.

I tried to hide the menu using basic css code to my select menu like so:

```
<select name="menu" id="related_calls_menu" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">....</select>
```

But this seems to be overridden by something in the bootstrap-multiselect. If I remove the plugin the the show/hide function works fine with no issue.

This is my current code for the menu

```
    $(function(){

        $("#related_calls_menu").multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            selectedClass: null,
            selectAllText: 'Select All',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select Related Account(s)',
            buttonWidth: '300px'
         });

        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#related_calls_menu").hide();
        });

        $('#complete_related_calls').click(function(){

            if( $(this).is(':checked') )
                $("#related_calls_menu").show();
            else
                $("#related_calls_menu").hide();
        });
    });
```

I have tried adding `.css('visability: hidden; display:none;');` to $("#related_calls_menu")

I have also tried adding this code

```
    $(window).on('load', function(){
        $("#related_calls_menu").hide();
    });
```

Nothing is really working, I can't seems to hide the menu what so ever. Also, when I click on the check box to show the menu I get a second menu that it does not have plugin look.

here is a screenshot BEFORE the check box

[image]

here is a screenshot AFTER the check box

[image]

Please Advise.

Comment: Well, the `select` is already hidden by bootstrap. What you need to hide is the `div` that the bootstrap adds. A quick solution would be to wrap the `select` inside another `div` element and then control that wrapping `div`

Comment: @Dola you are correct. Thanks for this solution. I added a wrapper dive and it solved my problem. if you post the answer I will mark it an the correct answer.  thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Select tag is already hidden by bootstrap.

put a wrapper div around your select tag like this

```
<div id="mywrapper">
  <select name="menu" id="related_calls_menu" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">....                    </select>
</div>
```

then you can control the wrapping div like this:

**CSS**:

```
#mywrapper{
display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#mywrapper").show();
$("#mywrapper").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some CSS code conflicting with bootstrap-select.

Inspect the element with your browser, go to "computed" and verify what is setting the "display" propriety of the element.

[image]

If you are on an emergency, you might set

```
#related_calls_menu{
  display: none!important;
}
```

in your stylesheet until you have this solved.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance . Looking the the display propriety body - block user agent stylesheet  I don't know if this is any help

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old post - however looks like you may have linked the JS file but not included the CSS - when I didn't link the CSS it caused this exact issue.

Make sure to link both of the below and see if that resolves it:

```
<!-- Include the plugins CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).